# Polyline is not rendering on maps while live reload is enabled

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I am using react-native-map package to draw a polyline using coordinates i am receiving in API call. Line is being drawn when HOT reload is enabled on expo but not when LIVE reload is enabled.

I have converted all coordinates to array of objects in following template. 
[{latitude:33.00, longitude:-74.00},{latitude:33.10, longitude:-74.02}]
And passed this array to coordinates in MapView.Polyline.

This how i am rendering MapView

```
<MapView
                    showsUserLocation
                    followsUserLocation
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    initialRegion={{
                        latitude: 31.5623499,
                        longitude: 74.3287183,
                        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                    }}>

                    {this.state.allPlants.map((item, index) => {
                    return <MapView.Marker
                    key={item.id.toString()}
                    coordinate={{
                    latitude: item.latitude,
                    longitude: item.longitude,
                    }}>
                    <Image source={item.isDead?require("../../assets/dead_tree.png"):require("../../assets/tree.png")} key={item.id.toString()} />                  </MapView.Marker>
                    })}

                    <MapView.Polyline
                        coordinates={this.allCoords}
                        strokeWidth={6}
                        strokeColor="red"
                        fillColor="rgba(100,0,0,0.5)"
                        />
                </MapView>
```

And this is how i am creating array of coordinates objects

```
        let tmpArray=[]
        if(tmp.length!==0){
            for(let i=0; i<tmp.length;i++){
                let tmpObj={
                    latitude:tmp[i].latitude,
                    longitude:tmp[i].longitude
                }
                tmpArray.push( tmpObj)
            }
        }
        this.allCoords=tmpArray
```

It should be able to show polyline as it is already showing on HOT reloading, i don't understand if that is the expected behavior or this is some bug.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped MapView code into following

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
 {this.state.isDataFetched && (
 <MapView
                    showsUserLocation
                    followsUserLocation
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    initialRegion={{
                        latitude: 31.5623499,
                        longitude: 74.3287183,
                        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                    }}>

                    {this.state.allPlants.map((item, index) => {
                    return <MapView.Marker
                    key={item.id.toString()}
                    coordinate={{
                    latitude: item.latitude,
                    longitude: item.longitude,
                    }}>
                    <Image source={item.isDead?require("../../assets/dead_tree.png"):require("../../assets/tree.png")} key={item.id.toString()} />                  </MapView.Marker>
                    })}

                    <MapView.Polyline
                        coordinates={this.allCoords}
                        strokeWidth={6}
                        strokeColor="red"
                        fillColor="rgba(100,0,0,0.5)"
                        />
                </MapView>
)}
</View>
```

And used `this.state.isDataFetched` as a flag to condition rendering and it worked as expected.